# Create color overlay when checkbox selected using z-index

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a check box that will be used to select a table with product info. Once selected a css style is to overlay a color at 30% so that it’s obvious that item is selected.

Using just css and jquery I can invoke the style that has a greater z-index than the image that is being used to visually see the overlay. The overlay style works and shows the correct z-index but it is not over the image.

Using Jquery I have forced the z-index of the image back to a -10 value. Still shows on top of the colored div…
I can even force the div in the same Jquery to move to z-index 105 but still it is not shown over the top of the image that is on a lesser z-index.

I’m thinking the problem is that the the div receiving the greater z-index is taking everything within it UP as the starting point so the nested image is also moved up in z-index level.

If that’s the case, how best to do an overlay on a series of dynamically generated tables that need to be covered with the 30% opacity style?

UPDATED WORKING CODE:

```
 $(function ()
    {          
        $("input[type='checkbox']").change(function ()
        {
            if ($(this).is(":checked"))
            {
                $(this).parent().addClass("jobSelected");
            } else
            {
                $(this).parent().removeClass("jobSelected");
            }
        });
    });   
    </script>



<style type="text/css">
.jobSelected {
    background-color: hsla(0,0%,0%,0.50);
    position: relative;
}
</style>
```

UPDATED WORKING CODE:

```
<div>
  <table  cellpadding="6" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="100%">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <td> Item 1 </td>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td><img src="http://sgdesign.com/temp/temp1.png" alt="" style="z-index:-1; position:relative;"></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" id="checkbox">
  Select </div>


<br>
<br>


<div>
  <table  cellpadding="6" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="100%">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <td > Item 2 </td>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td valign="top" style="border-left:0px none;padding-left:12px;"><img src="http://sgdesign.com/temp/temp2.png" alt="" style="z-index:-1; position:relative;"></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>

    <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox2" id="checkbox2">
  Select </div>
```

The code above does a great job of setting the expected values that can be seen by doing a browser Inspect Element but it's the results that are not acheiving the goal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to be sure that there are no elements that are wrapping your selection in a higher z-value than the dynamic updated value.

For instance:

```
  <tr>
    <td valign="top" style="border-left:0px none;padding-left:12px;">
        <div style="z-index:100; position:relative;" class="overlay">
            <img src="http://sgdesign.com/temp/temp1.png" alt="" style="z-index:-1; position:relative;">
        </div>
    </td>
    </tr>
```

We see a div wrapping the image at a z-index depth of 100, while the css that jquery sets is at 50. Removing the div with the 100 z-index value allows the jquery updated css at 50 to properly overlay.

Answer (score 0):

You are correct, the Z-index changes do not cascade, since you are dealing with a table. In order to get around that, change the z-index directly on the div where it is needed.

Try changing your CSS to this:

```
.jobSelected {
    background-color: hsla(0,0%,0%,0.30);
    position: relative;
}

.jobSelected div.overlay {
    z-index: 50;
}
```

Of course, your HTML should be updated too:

```
    <tr>
    <td valign="top" style="border-left:0px none;padding-left:12px;">
        <div style="z-index:100; position:relative;" class="overlay">
            <img src="http://sgdesign.com/temp/temp1.png" alt="" style="z-index:-1; position:relative;">
        </div>
    </td>
    </tr>
```

Comment: Garcia, thank you for your answer.
The problem was that a div, setting a z-index of 100 was wrapping the image and causing it to retail a higher z-index.

I've updated my example above to show the working versions as an assistance to others.

Comment: @Burndogz Glad you figured it out. Since you copied the code from my answer to paste into yours, I think the right thing to do would be to accept my answer.

Comment: Garcia, Actually you will see the only reference to your code is the removed div that was at z-index: 100. Check my CSS also as it does not use the additional style you added. I agree, you helped and are the reason I was able to find a working solution but the full example and self answered question provide a workable solution to anyone that runs into a similar problem. I'm trying to do the "right" thing.

Comment: In that case, you should at least accept your own answer. Questions without accepted answers are not as helpful.

Comment: I tried... It says I need to wait till tomorrow :-/  (not enough street creds yet)